# I'm going to be in England next week

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs, future-time

As far as I know this sentence is well constructed:

> I'm going to be in England next week.

I know it is wrong to think that certain English expressions must adjust to Spanish logic since they are two very different languages; having said that, I would like to understand why the verb *to be* is used twice? I can understand the presence of the personal pronoun *I* and that of the verb *to be* the second time it appears, but why do we have to conjugate it the first time (*I **am** going...*)?

Answer (score 2):

**I'm in England next week** is perfectly grammatical. It relies upon "next week" to express the idea of the future while using present tense. I believe that is what you had in mind when referring to what can be said in Spanish.

But we can express the future in another way too.

We can say

> I am to be in England next week.
>
> I will|shall be in England next week.
>
> I am going to be in England next week.

Let's work backwards.  The sentence with "am going to be" has a finite BE and a non-finite BE.

**to be in England** refers to a non-finite (i.e. outside of chronological time) existential/locative state, namely *(being)-there-in-England*.

Now, put  **going** in front of the above, and you project that non-finite existential/locative state into the future, since *going* + infinitive places the action or state of the verb in the future:

**going to be in England**, namely, *in-future-(being)-there-in-England*.

Now, put **I am** in front of that, and you complement the bald existential statement "I am" with the existential/locative "in-future-(being)-there-in-England".

In other words, your current intention is to be in England next week.

Comment: What about **I hadn't been in Scotland before** or **Have you ever been in California?** Are these fine too?

Comment: @MvLog **I hadn't been in Scotland before** would be used when talking about the past, when you visited Scotland for the first time. Your other point would be better as **Have you ever been to California?**

Comment: I'm sorry but **Longman Dictionary of Common Errors** cites these as incorrect, there should be **to** instead of **in** in both cases.

Comment: **to** refers to the place as a destination.  **in** refers to the place as a bounded area.  There are contexts for each. **in** is not "incorrect" when it is used  in the proper context.  *I've never been **in** Spain. But I've been **to** Spain.  I drove to the border but couldn't get into the country because I'd misplaced my passport.*